# Need help understanding the total number of different one-to-one functions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I am currently reading [Discrete Mathematics by Gary Chartrand and Ping Zhang](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1577667301) and in the book it has this section about the total number of one-to-one functions:

> **Theorem:** If A and B are two sets with |A| = m and |B| = n, where m $\leq$ n, then number of different one-to-one functions is $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$.

> **Proof:** First consider the special case where m = n, then the total number of possible one-to-one functions is n! — next, if m < n then the total number of one-to-one functions is $n(n-1)(n-2)...(n - m +1)$, multiplying this by $\frac{(n-m)!}{(n-m)!}$ we see the answer can now be expressed as $n(n-1)(n-2)...(n - m +1) \frac{(n-m)!}{(n-m)!} = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$

Two questions:

1. Where did $(n-m+1)$ come from?
2. Why does multiplying $n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-m+1)$ by $\frac{(n-m)!}{(n-m)!}$ result in $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Where did $(n-m+1)$ come from?*"

$\underbrace{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot (n-3)\cdots (n-m+1)}_{m~\text{total terms in the product}}$

The first term is $n$.  The second term is $n-1$.  The third term is $n-2$ and so on... to the $m$'th term being $n-m+1$.  If it helps you to see this, consider writing it instead as $n-(m-1)$ instead.

"*Why does multiplying by $\frac{(n-m)!}{(n-m)!}$ result in $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$?*"

Recall that $n! = n\cdot (n-1)! = n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)! = \dots = n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdots 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$ is the product of all positive integers up to $n$.  Here... we can recognize that $n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdots (n-m+1) \cdot (n-m)!$ as being one of those expressions in the middle of the above... that all together the numerator becomes the product of all positive integers up to $n$.

---

As an aside, I prefer writing the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) as $n\frac{m}{~}$.

Answer (score 1):

As the proof indicates, when m=n, then there are n! possible functions.  n! can be rewritten as:

$n!=n*(n-1)*(n-2)...2*1$

Note then that since m=n then $n-m+1=n-n+1=1$, so the above expression is synonymous with $n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*(n-m+1)$.

Or in other words, when n=m, then $(n-m+1)=1$.

So think about cases where m<n.  When m=n-1 then $(n-m+1)=(n-(n-1)+1)=(1+1)=2$.  When m=n-2 then $(n-(n-2)+1)=(2+1)=3$.  Etc.  So the (n-m+1) is the construction of the final number in the counting.

For your second question, let's go back to the longer expression.  When we have something like m=n-5 then we would have:

$n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*n-(n-5)+1=n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*(5+1)$

If we continued to multiply lessening values (*5*4*3*2*1) then we'd have n!.  Or in other words, this is just n! divided by 5*4*3*2*1=5! Ie - $\frac{n!}{5!}$.  And of course in this case, n-m=n-(n-5)=5, so that expression is the $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$ - the number of one-to-one functions.

Thinking about it like this bypasses the "multiply by $\frac{(n-m)!}{(n-m)!}" step, but obviously that fraction is equal to 1 so that multiplication is just a method of rewriting the one expression as the other.